# Change product Status in magento order with SOAP API v2

Tags: php, api, rest, magento, soap

We have a problem in Magento with SOAP V2 to change the "product processing status" in the magento order.

Our Magento Webshop:
We received an order from our webshop visitors .
Now we have a Magento order with several products.
Each product have a SKU and product ID...

**Every product have a processing status:**
"Product not in stock. We order the product for you. Please wait".
We use a custom product attribute in magento for this.

And if we have few days later the product in stock, we want to change the status to "Your product is now in stock."

**Our question is**:
How we can set the product status in the order with SOAP API v2 to change it to "Your product is now in stock."? And our website visitor can check the status in her user account.

Do you have any ideas?